# Three20: example of showMenu:forCell

Tags: ios4, cell, three20

I am not able to find any example that uses this function.
I need to see how implement a menu selecting a row in a table.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [TTTableViewController showMenu:forCell: example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620167/tttableviewcontroller-showmenuforcell-example)?

The last comment on the only answer has a link to a github that has some example code.  I think the author of the only answer is also the person who wrote http://cybersam.com/programming/tttableviewcontroller-showmenuforcell-example